# what is a meaning of しければ in a classical japanese?

Tags: classical-japanese

I'm stuck with this sentence - "いかにも山の中に只だ独り居たるに人の気はひのしければ少し生き出づる心地して見出だしければ"

It's part of the folktale "鬼に瘤取らるる事". I know that ば mean to indicate end of statement in classical japanese, so does it mean to be some sort of connection word in this case?

In modern japanese it has みる at the end -  "山の中にたったひとりでいたところに、人のいる感じがしたので少しほっとして外を見てみる"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

見出だす{みいだす}→見出だし{みいだし}(連用形{れんようけい})→見出だし{みいだし}＋けり→見出だし{みいだし}けれ(已然形{いぜんけい})＋ば→見出だ{みいだ}**しければ**

しければ is just the 連用形{れんようけい}/masu stem of a verb together with the auxiliary verb [けり](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009003.htm) in 已然形{いぜんけい} form, with the particle ば attached to it.

Comment: 「見出だし」は連用形で「けれ」は已然形なので、"the same way"は語弊があるのでは。

Comment: @naruto その通りです。‌​答えを修正します。　ありがとうございます！